# Is there a way to dereference parameters across different facets in Solr?

Tags: solr

I have a Solr JSON facet query which calculates a metric for the present year. I want to enhance this query to calculate this exact metric for the previous year as well and then calculate the ratio of increase/decrease.

Here is the JSON facet query that I have written so far -

```
 json.facet={
  "thisYear": {
    "type": "terms",
    "field": "<some-value>",
    "domain": {
      "filter": "<query to identify this year's document>"
    },
    "facet": {
      "thisYearFacet": "<the metric calculated for the present year>"
    }
  },
  "lastYear": {
    "type": "terms",
    "field": "<some-value>",
    "domain": {
      "filter": "<query to identify last year's document>"
    },
    "facet": {
      "lastYearFacet": "<the metric calculated for the last year>"
    }
  },

  // Here is where I am facing trouble!
  "compare": {
    "type": "func",
    "func": "avg(div($thisYearFacet,$lastYearFacet))"
  }
}
```

But running the above query throws the following error -

```
"error":{
"metadata":[
  "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
  "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError"],
"msg":"org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Missing param thisYearFacet while parsing function 'avg(div($thisYearFacet,$lastYearFacet))'",
"code":400}}
```

Is there a way to make the calculated variables "thisYearFacet" and "lastYearFacet" accessible in the "compare" facet?